# Can't access Procedure.reason in FHIR model

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, hl7-fhir, dstu2-fhir

I'm using the Fhir-net-api with DSTU2 to parse JSON objects to C# models. Everything works well, except that I can't access the *Reason* element of the resource type *Procedure*. As an example, I parse following JSON object to the Procedure model using the *FhirParser*:

```
{
"resourceType": "Procedure",
"identifier": [
    {
        "system": "https://mrd2.melanoma.org.au/fhir",
        "value": "100200199664802"
    }
],
"subject": { "reference": "Patient/10101000001733" },
"status": "completed",
"category": {
    "coding": [
        {
            "system": "https://mrd2.melanoma.org.au/fhir/RootType",
            "code": "3004"
        }
    ],
    "text": "Primary Surgery"
},
"bodySite": [
    {
        "coding": [
            {
                "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",
                "code": "7771000"
            }
        ],
        "text": "Left Forearm, Anterior"
    }
],
"reasonReference": { "reference": "/Condition/10106000001807" },
"performedDateTime": "1968-03-11",
"report": [ { "reference": "/DiagnosticReport/100200199664828" } ]
}
```

and the generated object has following entries (excerpt):
[Procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pO7X.png)

I can access `Report[0].Reference` just fine but it won't work with `Reason.Reference`. Is the data in my JSON object wrong?
I've seen that *Reason* is of type *Hl7.Fhir.Model.Element* and *Report* of type *Hl7.Fhir.Model.ResourceReference*. Is there a way to change *Reason* to *Hl7.Fhir.Model.ResourceReference* and then access the *Reference* element?

Would be grateful for any hints. Thanks.

Regards,

Trammy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed, the type of `reasonReference` is `Model.Element`, while the type of `report` is `ResourceReference`. This difference has its origin in the definition of these elements in the [FHIR specification for Procedure](http://www.hl7.org/fhir/procedure.html), where `report` is fixed to the type `Reference` but `reason` (or rather `reason[x]`) can either be a  `CodeableConcept` or a `Reference`.

When elements can be of multiple types (we call this a "choice element", and you can recognize them because their name ends with `[x]` in the specification), we have created a C# member that is of type `Model.Element` (the base class for both Reference and CodeableConcept).

Now, depending on the instance you have just parsed or received, the contents of the `reason` member can be one of both types. So, you'll have to check in your code:

```
if(Reports[0].reason is ResourceReference)
{
    var reference = (ResourceReference)Reports[0].reason;
    //handle the case where this is a reference
    //doing reference.Reference will now work as expected
}
else if(Reports[0].reason is CodeableConcept)
{
    var concept = (CodeableConcept)Reports[0].reason;
    //handle the case where this is a codeable concept
}
else
{
    // Oops! Should not happen unless the standard has changed
}
```

Of course, if you are sure you can only receive instances where reason is a ResourceReference, you can do a cast directly:

```
var myReference = (ResourceReference)Reports[0].Reference;
// myReference.Reference and myReference.Display will now work
```

Comment: Great. That should be feasible enough on my end. I haven't thought of simply casting the object to the desired type. Thanks